# How to move cursor in a specific column

Tags: vimrc, cursor-movement, macvim

I know that there is already a method to move the cursor to a particular line in vim like `:25` and it moves to line number 25. But can I configure vim to move to 15th column in 25th line say something like this `:25:15` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to do it from the normal mode, just type: `15|`. If you want to move to 15th column in 25th, type `25G15|`. If you want to do it as a command you can type: `:call cursor(25,15)` but I think it is easier to type `25G15|`.